# IExpress stop deleting files from temporary location

Tags: c#, visual-studio, iexpress

I have used IExpress for self extractor. I want to prevent files deleting from temporary location. Is it possible or not?

if not then any other self extractor can do the same or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be *directly* possible using IExpress, though you can work around it in a kludgy manner. There are other archivers that can do this directly; WinRAR springs to mind, though I'm sure there are more.

IExpress appears to have three modes:

1. Extract files to a temporary directory (seems to be something like `%temp%\IXP000.TMP`), run an installation command, run an optional post-installation command, delete the temporary directory.
2. Extract files; the location must either be specified on the command line, or the user will be prompted for a location. (I couldn't see any way to set the extract directory in the Wizard or the `.sed` file.)
3. Create a `.cab` file. (But honestly, I'd just use `makecab` or `cabarc`…)

One workaround is to bundle an IExpress archive *within* an IExpress archive; the inner archive (which contains your actual files) is the extract-only type (2), and the outer archive (which only contains your inner archive) is the installer type (1). The outer IExpress archive has an installation command like:

```
cmd /c innerArchive.exe /q /t:"%temp%\persistent"
```

That will leave files in `%temp%\persistent`. (The `cmd /c` is needed to perform variable expansion on `%temp%`.)

If you actually need to run a command to install something, you can specify it as the post-install command (referencing `%temp%\persistent` if you're running a file from the inner archive). Again you might need `cmd /c` to expand that.

---

Another method which is perhaps more straightforward is a simple batch file:

```
@echo off
xcopy /y * "%temp%\persistent\"
rem Execute any other commands here...
```

Then you only need one IExpress archive, an installer type (1) that executes the batch file. Make sure you run it like `cmd /c persist.bat` – otherwise it will be executed by `command.com`, which is not good.